# Error while training YOLO model: ValueError in ultralytics dataset.py line 139

Tags: ultralytics

[C:\Users\prime\anaconda3\envs\yolo_ultra_8083\lib\site-packages\ultralytics\data\dataset.py", line 139, in get_labels len_cls, len_boxes, len_segments = (sum(x) for x in zip(*lengths)) ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 0)]

I have got while training the model with 3 bounding box and 11 key points below code snippet of training
from ultralytics import YOLO

```
model = YOLO('yolov8m-pose.pt')
model.train(data='config.yaml', epochs=500, imgsz=640)
```

model has to train properly with given epoch and give trained model for prediction